# How can I have two separate SAML applications login to an IdP without logging in twice?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, auth0, onelogin

I have four custom apps (that are SPs), using Auth0 or OneLogin as my IdP.  In Auth0 I create a connector for each application.  When I login to one application and then open the other application, I get redirected to Auth0 to login again.

Is it possible to log the user into my IdP (or Auth0/OneLogin) automatically on that second app without having to click the login button on Auth0, since they've already authenticated with Auth0?

There is an unfortunate need to embed the second app into the first app and it's a poor UX to have the user login to the first app and then login again in the iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 Dev here, Yes this is supported Out of the box in Auth0, for this to work you'd have to turn Use Auth0 as IdP "ON" in your Client. When doing this Auth0 will then remember the client for 10 hours upto 3 days if the client is active.

The flow in your scenario will be

- User logs in to any of the application.
- User visits the other application.
- The other application sees no session.
- The other application redirects to `/authorize` endpoint.
- Auth0 notices the session and redirects it back to your application immediately.

This is further detailed and explained at https://auth0.com/docs/sso

Answer (score 1):

SSO is not having to re-enter credentials again but you only get SSO once you redirect to the IDP and you authenticate under the hood i.e. seamlessly.

So you still have to do something to trigger the redirect.

You could programmatically redirect to a dummy page that requires authentication that then redirects via your client stack e.g. OWIN OIDC.

Also, there is no standard for the cookies so you don't get SSO across multiple IDP unless they are federated together.

So if no federation and you login to Auth0, you will still have to login to OneLogin.